# How to insert a field for characters with spaces?

Tags: microsoft-word

I can insert a field with total amount of characters without spaces in the document with NumChars but is there a similar way to display characters with spaces too?

Comment: Are you using VBA for this? If so, what do you have so far? Or are you using a Quick Parts field?

Comment: I was thinking about the quick parts, yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can insert a field that counts also spaces. Insert **DocProperty** field with **CharactersWithSpaces** property.

Comment: This! just tested it with a =rand(1) and it works a treat.